# Calling Multiple Activity classes in a single screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

Can we make use of multiple `Activity` classes in a single screen of Android app?

For example, make use of multiple `Activity` classes to call different web services and populate information on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

A activity represents one screen on android. I think Fragments are what you search for. With Fragments you can show more layouts on one screen.

Comment: so what I understand is that using Fragments we should be able to multiple web services i.e each fragment calling one WS

Comment: You can also call multiple web services in different threads ( asynctask for example ) and create a layout which will show the result in only one activity. But i still think fragments is what you want so you can easy reuse the activitys.